# BigInteger Constant behaviour

Tags: java, integer, logic, biginteger

**Why below statement return false?**

```
BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger("0");
System.out.println((BigInteger.ZERO == bigInteger));
```

What should i pass in new BigInteger(?) so condition will be true.

Comment: Call `BigInteger.ZERO.equals(bigInteger)`. This is not a primitive.

Comment: I would suspect that `System.out.println((BigInteger.ZERO.equals(bigInteger)));` prints `true`...

Comment: can someone pleaseanswer what BigInteger.Zero is equal to? Is it not a primitive value ?

Comment: @arjunkumarmehta no, it is not. Java has eight primitive data types, they are listed [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). `BigInteger` is not one of them. You never call `new ...` on a primitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By specification, `new` always creates a new instance (or it fails).

Whatever instance is assigned to `BigInteger.ZERO`, it's not the one you create in your code with `new BigInteger("0")`.

Since it's not the same instance, and `==` only returns true if the operands refer to the same instance (provided they are both reference types, which they are in this case), the result is false.

---

You almost never want to compare objects using `a == b` or `a != B`. You should use `a.equals(b)` or `!a.equals(b)` instead. (Or `Objects.equals`, if `a` might be null).